# Using eval and comparison's

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that compares the value of a key in an object. I want to use the 'this' keyword to refer to the key value, however the value maybe a primitive not an object. To do this I'm using eval to evaluate the value of the the key in an if statement.

So I can do cool stuff like this...

```
    bar.find({ key: 'this - 2 === 5' });

    bar.find({ key2: 'this.length === 11' });

    // In order to do this I have a function similar to this

    // constructor function for my object
    function foo(arg){
        this.key = 5;
        this.key2 = 'hello world';
    };

    // method to find if matching key values exist
    foo.prototype.find = function(args){
        // variable to hold the contents of the anonymous function
        var compare;

        // create an anonymous function to shield the eval from executing
        // potentially harmful code, by overwriting the document and window.
        (function(window, document){                
            compare = function(comparison){
                if ( eval( comparison ) )
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            };              
        })();

        // Loop over the keys in args
        for( i in args ){
            if ( this[i] ) {
                // call the compare function bound to the scope of the
                // keys value
                return compare.call(this[i], args[i]);  
            }
            else {
                return false;
            };      
        };
    };

    // Create an new foo object

    bar = new foo;

    // test it, should return true

    bar.find({key: 'this - 2 === 3', key2: 'this.length === 11'});
    >> false // 5 - 2 === 3
    >> false // 'hello world'.length === 11
```

The issue that I'm having is not that the code doesn't work. the exactly === operator doesn't work, however the == operator works fine.

If I do

```
    bar.find({key: 'this - 2 == 3', key2: 'this.length == 11'});
    >> true // 5 - 2 == 3
    >> true // 'hello world'.length == 11
```

Is this something that eval is doing, causing the types not to match?

Or if anyone has a better alternative to achieve the same thing.

Comment: just fyi - there is no such thing as a 'primitive' in javascript.  Everything is an object.  Don't believe me?  Try it: `Number.prototype.foo='bar';alert((1).foo)`

Comment: @digitalbath that's not correct. JavaScript aggressively promotes primitive values (strings, numbers, booleans) to Object types when appropriate, but primitives really are primitive.

Comment: All you are proving there is that Numbers prototype is an object.

Comment: @ashmokhberi any use of "eval()" is inherently suspect. What exactly is it that you want to be able to do? It's very hard to understand the examples.

Comment: Pointy is correct.  1 === new Number(1) returns false.

Comment: you _can_ prevent `eval` from touching the wrong scope by using `with`.  However that's _also_ deprecated in ES5.

Comment: @jimbojw I don't think just saying no to something is an answer. Eval is remarked to be bad however, many people misunderstand it, and many of the top JS guys use it. It's not about saying no it's about learning when you can say yes.

Comment: I would love to know who gave my question a down vote and why

Answer (score 0):

Worksforme on v8. I don't see how eval could mess up the types.

Generally there is no need to use eval, it's slow, and perhaps a bit more concise than passing functions but I would still prefer functions, so you could change the arguments to `bar.find({key: function () { return this - 2 === 3 }, key2: function () { return this.length === 11 })`.

Comment: Oh and also, the way you're trying to secure the global scope won't work, `(function (window) { eval("x = 1"); })()` will still set x in the global scope.

Comment: that could work but, I prefer the much shorter more readable method.

Comment: You are correct about the global thing. I was not thinking that far ahead. I was mainly thinking that with no window or document they could not do   `document.querySelector('head').appendChild(some-Dangerous-script)`  But you are right than can still do it :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval` it'll call everything in global scope so your value of `this` will be incorrect.

Use callback functions directly, so your code would look more like:

```
bar.find({
    key: function() { return this - 2 === 3; },
   key2: function() { return this.length === 11; }
});
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that (the global scope thing), but couldn't figure out why this.length == 11 was working for him if that was true.  Of course, I haven't tested eval with this myself.

Comment: you can copy the code into the console it will work.The reason this.length == 11 is working is because I call the function into the context of the keys value using func.call(obj[i], arg[i]). I then pass in the argument to the function to be eval()'d